# Create a Python User() class that both creates new users and modifies existing users

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a class that can modify and create new users all in one.  This is what I'm thinking:

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self,user_id):
      if user_id == -1
          self.new_user = True
      else:
          self.new_user = False

          #fetch all records from db about user_id
          self._populateUser() 

    def commit(self):
        if self.new_user:
            #Do INSERTs
        else:
            #Do UPDATEs

    def delete(self):
        if self.new_user == False:
            return False

        #Delete user code here

    def _populate(self):
        #Query self.user_id from database and
        #set all instance variables, e.g.
        #self.name = row['name']

    def getFullName(self):
        return self.name

#Create a new user
>>u = User()
>>u.name = 'Jason Martinez'
>>u.password = 'linebreak'
>>u.commit()
>>print u.getFullName()
>>Jason Martinez

#Update existing user
>>u = User(43)
>>u.name = 'New Name Here'
>>u.commit()
>>print u.getFullName()
>>New Name Here
```

Is this a logical and clean way to do this?  Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you set `self.new_user` to True in `commit()` after you performed the insertion successfully, otherwise you might be in trouble if you call `commit()` twice on the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would suggest the following:

1: Use a default argument `None` instead of -1 for `user_id` in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, user_id=None):
    if user_id is None:
         ...
```

2: Skip the `getFullName` method - that's just your Java talking.  Instead use a normal attribute access - you can convert it into a property later if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with metaclasses. Consider this :

```
class MetaCity:
    def __call__(cls,name):
        “”“
            If it’s in the database, retrieve it and return it
            If it’s not there, create it and return it
        ““”
            theCity = database.get(name) # your custom code to get the object from the db goes here
            if not theCity:
                # create a new one
                theCity = type.__call__(cls,name)

        return theCity

class City():
    __metaclass__ = MetaCity
    name   = Field(Unicode(64))
```

Now you can do things like :

```
paris = City(name=u"Paris") # this will create the Paris City in the database and return it.
paris_again = City(name=u"Paris") # this will retrieve Paris from the database and return it.
```

from : http://yassinechaouche.thecoderblogs.com/2009/11/21/using-beaker-as-a-second-level-query-cache-for-sqlalchemy-in-pylons/

Comment: Page in the link disappeared. Here's an [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100201173234/http://yassinechaouche.thecoderblogs.com/) of the home page (you have to scroll to the relevant article "using baker as a secod level query cache for sqlalchemy in pylons") :

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is called [Active Record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). I suggest learning existing systems providing this sort of things such as [Elixir](https://pypi.org/project/Elixir/).

Answer (score 1):

Small change to your initializer:

```
def __init__(self, user_id=None):
      if user_id is None:
```

Comment: And the same "don't use accessors" I gave in my other answer.